# How to scrape facebook page with php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** facebook page. I am using php.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html = file_get_html('http://www.facebook.com/');
// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
?>
```

But it gives -
[image]

**Above screenshot showing.- "Please update your browser".**

My browser is up to date. And If I **scrape** with **"http://www.google.com/"** then it is working nice. Am I on correct way? OR I have to try anything else. Please suggest anyone.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraped__, __scraping__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer:

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$options = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                  "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
                  "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n" // i.e. An iPad 
      )
    );

    // fetch webpage content
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
 $html = file_get_html('https://www.facebook.com', false, $context);

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('button') as $element) 
       echo $element. '<br>';
?>
```

But if I replace url with "https://www.facebook.com/techcrunch/about/". It requires login, why?

Comment: Asking further questions in answers is unlikely to get anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this

 $c = curl_init('https://www.facebook.com');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt(... other options you want...)
    
    $html = curl_exec($c);
    
    if (curl_error($c))
        die(curl_error($c));
    
    // Get the status code
    $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    
    curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Now blank screen. No output.

Comment: what have in simple_html_dom.php

Comment: simple_html_dom.php has lots of code and it is exceeding the limit. How can I show?

Comment: Can U please suggest any url to download the simple_html_dom.php?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Generally you would link to the library you're using, but I assume you were simply given the file and told to use it.


The original can be [found on github](https://github.com/simplehtmldom/simplehtmldom), but there is also a [commonly used fork](https://github.com/voku/simple_html_dom).

Examining the top of the file will probably tell you which it is and where it's from, assuming the license material hasn't been stripped from your copy.